Identify this movie about rival gangs in the 1960s
I am seeking a recent colour (2016?) movie which contains a speech in the end. 
It also has a white man who speaks weirdly but also very nicely in a strange camera angle.
I also remember two rival gangs which clash in one scene. The movie has a yellowish tone. 
In the scene when the crowd of people clash with the other, there is a police officer with a hitting stick. And i think they are trying to defend a boy.
There is also some African-American characters in it. I think it plays out in the 1960s. Could someone please help find this movie?

Note the speach is so nice

you had to remember it

You're still missing a lot of information. Read my initial comment and try to add as much as you can.

The main detail is the speach in the movie.

Lots of movies have speeches though. It's not much to go on.

when groups clash there is a police officer with a hitting stick

He has a very lean woice and he keeps speaking and the camera angle is fucked up

What was the speech about? Really...you need to [edit] as much information as possible into the question.

I dont remember what he was saying

Sounds like it might be Selma.  Set during the 1960's, features dramatic speeches, a yellowish or sepia tone in many scenes, and clashes with police.




Yeah! well done sir! Thank you so much Lazy.
